# SP2013 - Randomly getting an error while clicking on the ellipsis of a document in a Document Library

Tags: 2013, document-library

I have a standard out-of-the-box Document Library. Versioning and checking are enabled. There are a few extra columns added to the library. There is this a weird random behavior when clicking on the ellipsis (...) button on a document. Sometimes it will display the context menu and sometimes it will give me this error:

TypeError: Unable to get property 'FileLeafRef' of undefined or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property 'ItemType' of undefined or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property 'ID' of undefined or null reference

Sometimes a refresh will fix it. Sometimes it won't. It's all pretty random.

Anyone have this issue or have any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not alone.
There is a proposed workaround in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1c38e04c-ffc7-462e-a3ed-b6c23ccdfca7/sharepoint-2013-getting-an-error-while-clicking-on-the-ellipsis-of-a-document-in-a-document?forum=sharepointgeneral